# Denote list to extract parts

Tags: list, ocaml

I have a database table that I have tried to model in OCaml. However, I get problems when I try to write a function that extracts columns. I have managed to write a function that takes a table with only one column, but if I have a table with more columns then I get a match failure. I would need help with how to denotate my table in my pattern matching.

```
   (* Table with many columns *)
    let tableWithManyColumns = 
    "carTable",
    [   ("RegNumber", ["1";"2";"3";"4"]);
        ("Brand", ["BMW";"SAAB";"Volvo";"Jeep"]);
        ("Year",["2000";"2003";"2001";"2012"]); 
   ];;

      (*Table with one columns*)
     let tableWithOneColumn = "carTable",
     [   
      ("RegNumber", ["1";"2";"3";"4"])  
    ];;

     (*Current extractColumn*)
       let extractColumn (t:string * (string * string list) list) = 
          match t with 
          (a,[(b,c)])-> b;;

     (* Returns Regnumber *)
        extractColumn(tableWithOneColumn);;

     (*Returns match failure*)
        extractColumn(tableWithManyColumns);;
```

Comment: I wonder why I should bother to read code formatted like this. If you ask others for help, you might at least put in a little bit of effort to make it as easy as possible to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `[(b,c)]` matches with a singleton list of pairs. So it will match with `[("hello", "world)]` but will not match with `[("hello", "world"); ("another", "pair")]`, or `[]` or any list which length is not equal to one. If you want to match with any list with length more than one, you need to use the `first :: rest` pattern, where `first` will match with the first element of the list, and `rest` with the rest part of the list (everything beyond the first element).

The following function will extract the name of the first column,

```
type column = string * string list (* name, values *)
type base = string * column list (* tableName, columns *)

let firstColumnName : base -> string = fun table -> match table with
   | (_tableName, (columnName,_values) :: _otherColumns) -> columnName
   | _ -> failwith "wrong table representation"
```

Example,

```
# firstColumnName tableWithOneColumn;;
- : string = "RegNumber"
# firstColumnName tableWithManyColumns;;
- : string = "RegNumber"
```